# Find area of Lune from width at largest point and tip-to-tip distance

Tags: geometry, area

Need to find the area of a lune.

[image]

The only measurements we have are:

- It is 17 inches wide at the widest point (in the middle)
- It is 88 inches from tip to tip

Is this possible? I feel like we need 1 more measurement. Is it not true that there is only 1 unique solution to this problem though? That makes me feel like it should be possible.

Comment: Although there may be many lunes that meet the criteria, it is possible that they all have the same area...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. Can you help me visualize two different lunes that meet the criteria?

Comment: I was able to construct two lunes, having the same two distances $(3$ and $7.84)$, but two different areas $(21.5$ and $33.66)$.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I wasn't sure whether this was going to be an interesting property of lunes. Apparently not, so it seems like one more piece of information is necessary!